# Expressing a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $C=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ be bases to $V$. Suppose: $w_i=m_{i1}v_1+...+m_{in}v_n$ for $m_{ij}\in F, 1\le i,j \le n$. $M$ is an invertible matrix whose ($i,j$) member is $m_{ij}$.

I need to express the transformation matrix, $N$, from $B$ to $C$ by $M$. ($\forall v\in V [v]_C = N[v]_B$).

Is this true?
$$(w_1 \dots w_n)^{-1} (v_1 \dots v_n) = N\\
\big((v_1 \dots v_n)M^t)^{-1}(v_1 \dots v_n) = N\\
(M^t)^{-1}(v_1 \dots v_n)^{-1}(v_1 \dots v_n)=N\\
(M^{-1})^t=N$$

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

The identity transformation 
$$\mathrm{Id}\colon V\to V$$
is an isomorphism of vector spaces then we have
$$M=\mathrm{Mat}_{C\to B}(\mathrm{Id})$$
hence $M$ is invertible and we have
$$N=\mathrm{Mat}_{B\to C}(\mathrm{Id})=M^{-1}$$

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not familiar with notations such as $\mathrm{Mat}_{C\to B}(\mathrm{Id})$. Can you clarify?

Comment: @yuvalz $\mathrm{Mat}_{C\to B}(f)$ means the matrix that represents the transformation $f:V\to W$ where $C$ is a basis chosen for the vector space $V$ and $B$ is a basis chosen for the vector space $W$